# ASP.Net MVC5 app only returns content on first request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

Sorry if this appears to be a partial duplicate of other questions found here but none of the other queries have helped this particular problem.

When rebooting my development machine I can get an IIS served MVC5 application to provide content one time and one time only. Every subsequent request returns a blank page with 200 OK. Obviously I have tried this is multiple browsers and also tried Postman and clearly the response the blank.

To confuse the situation a little, we have some functions in the app that return XML or JSON content directly without using Razor views and these work fine. The problem seems completely limited to Razor views.

On top of this the problem appears to be limited to my development machine, so I have been through the installed features for IIS with a fine-toothed comb so HTTP Errors, HTTP Redirection, Static Content etc. are all installed. I have also been through the IIS site and appPool settings so they match our test server and live server (where things still work).

No error messages are produced *anywhere*. I have tried Application_Error logging, the IExceptionFilter approach and nothing lands. EventViewer is also blank. Modifying the customErrors setting has no effect.

After spending a day with all this it seems that the problem lies with Visual Studio 2015. If the VS project is open, the MVC site fails as described. Close VS and it all comes to life.

It seems that changing the project settings to force Local IIS does not help and the option seems to periodically revert to IIS Express. Can I not just tell it to not worry about it?

Does anyone have any ideas how I can have VS open and still run the application without the Views silently failing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the ASP.NET Web server, when running, and IIS Pointing to the same directory for you application?

Comment: @Ross So when I set the project to Local IIS you don't get this option, am I right?

Comment: Just curious, what makes you need to connect via VS, assuming a debugger, and outside of VS?

Comment: @Ross Perhaps I wasn't clear. The blank pages result from requests in a normal browser. Normally I don't need to connect VS to the IIS process unless I am debugging. The issue is that even the mere presence of the open project in VS causes it to stop working. Ideally I'd like VS to not be involved at all unless I manually attach it to the IIS instance.

Comment: In IIS, are you mapping to your Debug/Bin or Release/Bin folder?

Comment: @Ross No, the main project path is mapped. Bin is just a part of it (and there's only bin, no debug or release split).